# Need explanation on network redundancy

Tags: networking

This is a practice question from Network+ exam, but I am not sure the given answer which is C & E, is right. Can someone explain it. Thank you.

Question: A technician needs multiple networks, high speeds, and redundancy on a system. Which of the following configurations should be considered for these requirements? (Select TWO).

A. Routing table
B. Next hop
C. Port mirroring
D. Port monitoring
E. VLANs

Comment: well, Port Mirroring is a technique to get a switch to send all the traffic it processes (well most of it anyway) out a single port. It is useful for sniffing traffic or running an Intrusion Detection system, since it allows the sniffer/ids to see all the traffic passing through the switch, rather than just the stuff sent to the sniffing/monitoring device. Mirroring would not really be useful for operational redundancy, because you would not want your frame to arrive at a destination twice. I will say, that that is an odd question considering the answer options. None of them are a full soution